# map response.json not working in provider

Tags: angular, http, observable

In my provider I am using

```
this
  .http
  .get('/login', options)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(response => {return response})
```

However, in my component the object returned is the full Response (header, status, body etc.)

Any reason this would break?
I should mention that I have extended Http to intercept and add headers to all requests. I am using the following rxjs methods to return an Observable:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/merge';
```

Also, when I run .json() on the returned object in my component, it works.
So the mapping function is not working, althuogh tslint is not showing any errors.

Comment: Are you using the old Http or the new HttpClient from 4.3?

Comment: I am using Http.
Since we are using the latest Ionic which does not have Angular 4.3 yet, I can't use HttpClient.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed to the following in my http custom interceptor and it works now:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/fromPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
```